# F# how to mirror a binary tree

Tags: f#, binary-tree, flip

New to F#
I am trying to flip the sub trees on the branches.

we must use the following data types

```
 type btree = Empty | Node of btree * int * btree
 type finding = NotFound | Found of int
```

example tree

```
 let s = Node (Node(Empty, 5, Node(Empty, 2, Empty)), 3, Node (Empty, 6, Empty))
 (*
      (3)
     /    \
    (5)   (6)
    / \   |  \
   () (2) () ()
      / \
     () ()
 *)
```

here is my code so far:

```
 let rec mirror t = function
     | Node(Empty, t, Empty) -> t 
     | Node (t1, t, t2) ->  
     | _ -> failwith "Empty"
```

example input and output:

```
 mirror (Node (Node (Empty, 1, Empty), 3, Node (Empty, 4, Node (Empty, 7, Empty)))
```

would return

```
 Node (Node (Node (Empty, 7, Empty), 4, Empty), 3, Node (Empty, 1, Empty))
```

Right now the code doesn't accomplish anything, I am needing help on how I would move a nodes around to get the mirrored tree that I want.

I wonder if I must implement another function for deleting/inserting nodes? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's not clear as to what your question is.

Comment: "Here's my code so far" What is your code doing that you don't want it to do? What is it not doing that you wish it was? You're going to need to include an actual question in this post if you want to get any help.

Comment: I edited question. Sorry for vagueness, I am pretty lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like homework, so I'll add a few learning points, before I 'hand over' the solution. Let's have a look at the code you have written already, which is not a terrible start. I have pasted it below for reference.

```
let rec mirror t = function
    | Node(Empty, t, Empty) -> t 
    | Node (t1, t, t2) ->  
    | _ -> failwith "Empty"
```

You start off with allowing your function to call itself recursively, by adding the `rec` keyword. You are right to do that, and it's actually a pretty important realisation, that the way to go about this task, is to create a recursive function. Because, really, what does it mean to 'mirror' a tree? Mirroring means, at each node, flip the order of the subtrees, and mirror each subtree.

This is a recursive definition, since to mirror a node, you need to mirror the subtrees. So you're right about adding the `rec` keyword. However, in your code, you don't properly handle the terminal state `Empty`. Using your `btree` definition, you *will* eventually see an `Empty` tree, which means you *will* eventually throw an exception (using the `failwith`). This is obviously not the desired behaviour. What does the mirror of an empty tree look like? Empty! The way to handle this case, is then to replace `| _ -> failwith "Empty"` with `| Empty -> Empty`.

Now, in F#, `let foo = function | ...` is just syntactic sugar for `let foo <arg> = match <arg> with | ...`, which means your function actually takes *two* parameters: `t` and one which is hidden by the `function` sugar. I suppose this is not what you want, so you should either remove the currently unused parameter `t`, or replace `function` with `match t with`.

The reason the parameter `t` is currently unused, is that `t` is rebound to the integer node-value in the match-cases `| Node(..., t, ...)`. This also means that the compilers current best guess, is probably that the return type of `mirror` should be `int`, rather than `btree`, since you return an `int` in the first case.

One last point is that there is no reason for handling the case with empty subtrees directly, since these are also just `btree`s.

Keeping all of the above in mind, I hope it makes sense why my solution to the problem is

```
let rec mirror = function
    | Empty -> Empty
    | Node(t1, i, t2) -> Node(mirror t2, i, mirror t1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Mirroring means making the left branch the right branch and the right branch the left branch. So in your recursive function do that. For example if you start with a basic 3 node tree:

```
   1
2     3
```

then mirroring that will be

```
    1
  3   2
```

So in code that means:

```
let rec mirror t = function
     | Node(Empty, t, Empty) -> t 
     | Node (left, value, right) -> Node (right, value, left)
```

Except that won't work for larger trees, but it's a start. What you really want is the mirror of the right and left nodes as well. You should be able to complete the function above by adding 2 calls to mirror in the correct place in the last line of the match clause.